# Memory leak in php extension wrapped with swig

Tags: php, memory, swig, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in a PHP extension wrapped with swig.

Consider the following function:

```
ZEND_NAMED_FUNCTION(_wrap_ArrayBase_get) {
  ArrayBase *arg1 = (ArrayBase *) 0 ;
  long arg2 ;
  zval **args[2];
  zval *result = 0 ;

  SWIG_ResetError();
  if(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 2 || zend_get_parameters_array_ex(2, args) != SUCCESS) {
    WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;
  }

  {
    if(SWIG_ConvertPtr(*args[0], (void **) &arg1, SWIGTYPE_p_ArrayBase, 0) < 0) {
      SWIG_PHP_Error(E_ERROR, "");
    }
  }

  if(!arg1) SWIG_PHP_Error(E_ERROR, "this pointer is NULL");

  /*@SWIG:/usr/local/share/swig/2.0.2/php/utils.i,7,CONVERT_INT_IN@*/
  convert_to_long_ex(args[1]);
  arg2 = (long) Z_LVAL_PP(args[1]);

  {
    try {
      result = (zval *)((ArrayBase const *)arg1)->get(arg2);
    } catch (PHPIteratorException& phpExcep ){
      //nothing to do, exception already created...  
    }
  {
    if ( result != NULL ){
      ZVAL_ZVAL(return_value,result,0,0);
    }
  }
  return;
fail:
  SWIG_ZEND_ERROR_NORETURN(SWIG_ErrorCode(),"%s",SWIG_ErrorMsg());
}
```

The call:

```
result = (zval *)((ArrayBase const *)arg1)->get(arg2);
```

initializes and sets the zval but this memory is never freed. How the zval is initialized can differ between child classes of ArrayBase due to primitive types. So for example for long type the getter would be something like:

```
zval* return_value; ALLOC_ZVAL(return_value); ZVAL_LONG(return_value, l);return return_value;
```

How can I free this memory? Is there a zend macro which needs to be called? 
Is this a swig issue that has maybe been resolved in newer versions? 
I'm using SWIG Version 2.0.2.

Comment: For some reason a part of the wrapper function is not shown correctly in the html. Have a look a the page source to see the call to the getter function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by fixing the zval type mapping function in swig. I call the FREE_ZVAL function on the input zval.

//Type maps for zval* - pass them straight in and out...

```
%typemap(out) zval*
{
    if ( $1 != NULL ){
        ZVAL_ZVAL(return_value,$1,0,0);
        FREE_ZVAL($1);
    }
}
```